# How to install cyanogen mod 12 lollipop?

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop

I have an unrooted Samsung ace 2. How do I install cm 12 lollipop on it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone is not official supported by CM12, but there is at least an inofficial build some enthusiasts created. Go to [CM Unofficial Ports List](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Unofficial_Ports). There are two inofficial builds created by different teams, so take time and read which one seems better.

But in such inofficial builds not everything may work, also I think you should somehow know what you are doing before starting to flash such ROMs.